# Can cassandra be used for likes / view counts

Tags: cassandra

Would cassandra be usable when you are storing data that contains something similar to likes or view counts?  As I see it the issues would be:

1) Constant updates to rows (tombstones)

2) Using a counter or LWT CAS operations would increase latency and be complicated.  Which is troublesome if updating view counts since that would be the most frequent operation.

Using a counter would be a write to the counter 'table' while a read of 100 records would require 100 reads or a select in on the counter table.

Using LWT would be a read of the row and a compare and set until your update sticks. Reads of 100 records would be as normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counter is built for these type of Job.**

> A counter is a special column used to store a number that is changed in increments. For example, you might use a counter column to count the number of times a page is viewed.
>   Apache Cassandra™ 2.1 counter column improves the implementation of counters and provides a number of configuration options to tune counters

You can create a counter table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE video_counter (
    video_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    like_count counter,
    view_count counter
);
```

Whenever a like or view request received for a video, increment the count.

```
//Like
UPDATE video_counter SET like_count = like_count + 1 WHERE video_id = ? ;

//View
UPDATE video_counter SET view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE video_id = ? ;
```

Now you can get the like and view count of a video very efficiently

```
SELECT * FROM video_counter WHERE video_id = ? ;
```

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Comment: Lets say I need to return a list of 1000 videos - would select * where video_id in (1...1000) be performant?  I would guess so since all 1000 video records would be on the same node.  I'm setting up the counter table now to try this.

Comment: Instead of using in clause, use separate query and execute using executeAsync. Check this https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries

Comment: Counter update is very Fast, It design to be update frequently. And LWT is very slow

Comment: Select in with < 1000 rows in the same partition for my counter table responds in on average 2ms which is less than a single select on my main table so its not bad.  I did not try LWT as the counter works for my project and now cassandra handles all my queries.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering If OP actually implemented the final solution using counters. Ane If did, what were the pitfalls.