# Apache Cassandra aggregation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have installed Cassandra on  cluster consist of 4 nodes (8 cores and 50 gigabyte RAM ) .
and I have inserted 85 Million row in Cassandra table about 28 gigabyte of data . i want to count all rows in the table and i have used this query

```
select count(*) from page_viewes;
```

this query takes around 30 min . my question is . how to reduce this time ?

Comment: What is your `page_viewes ` table schema ?

Comment: [Cassandra doesn’t maintain such counts, unlike the indexing structures used in relational databases. It’s not that someone didn’t bother to implement it, such a count would violate many of Cassandra’s principles.](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/counting-keys-in-cassandra)

Comment: Use counter https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218675/2320144